# Remove all inline style tage from HTML using dom

Tags: php, css, dom

I have a dom and in this i have loaded whole of the webpage html. I want to remove all the inline style from all the elements in this page. How can i do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     // Do something with the element here
     all[i].removeAttribute("style","")
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to do this using PHP.

Comment: Its better to process DOM on client side

Comment: What if the client's browser has js disabled? What if I wanted to remove the style as a server side validation of the data inputted by the client? It's not better to process DOM on client side, it depends on what you aim to do.

Answer (score 2):

Using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is the simpliest way.

Here's what I would do.

1. Load your markup using [loadHTML().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)
2. Select all elements with the `styles` attribute using [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).
3. Remove the styles attribute using [removeAttribute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.removeattribute.php) on each DOMElement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go throguh every element on the page and call `element.removeAttribute("style")` You can recursivley traverse the dom using javascript, there are plenty of examples of this online.